# Closure Compiler does not always inline enums. Why?

Tags: javascript, enums, google-closure-compiler

What are the rules that Google's Closure Compiler follows for deciding if an `enum` is going to be inline or not?

When I run my code through the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) the JSDoc [annotation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) `enum` type is not inlined. Yet when I create a simplified example, the `enum` types are inlined, as this nonsense example will demonstrate:

```
 var my_name_space = (function () {
     'use strict';

     /** @enum {number} */
     var TASK_STATUS = {
         REJECT: -1,
         UNKNOWN: 0,
         APPROVE: 1
     };

     function init_(a) {
         if (a === TASK_STATUS.UNKNOWN) {
             alert("Reject");
             a = TASK_STATUS.REJECT;
         } else if (a === TASK_STATUS.APPROVE) {
             alert("Unknown");
             a = TASK_STATUS.UNKNOWN;
         } else {
             alert("Approve");
             a = TASK_STATUS.APPROVE;
         }
         return a;
     }
     return { init: init_};

 }());  // my_name_space


 my_name_space.init(-1);
```

Closure's output:

```
 var my_name_space=function(){return{init:function(a){0===a?(alert("Reject"),a=-1):1===a?(alert("Unknown"),a=0):(alert("Approve"),a=1);return a}}}();my_name_space.init(-1);
```

In fact, in lining will occur with or without the JSDoc header.

Please explain under what conditions in lining would not occur, or even better, please make modification(s) to the above that would demonstrate when lining would not happen.

I'm using 'Simple' optimization level.

Answer (score 4):

First, enums aren't really special objects for optimization purposes, however, @enum is useful for type checking and has special rules for that purpose.

As for inlining, there are many things that would prevent inlining, it isn't reasonable to demonstrate all the possibilities, but I can give you an idea as to why they might not be:

- The enum object is defined as a property on object that can't be decomposed into variable (ADVANCED mode helps here)
- The enum is defined on a global variable (ADVANCED mode helps here)
- The enum object is aliased in a way that the alias itself can't be removed (passing the enum object to a function that can't be inlined, assigning the enum object to a global value).
- Iterating over the enum keys/values (for-in, etc)
- The enum object is overwritten

These all come down to not the compiler being able to determine that it can:

- remove the object and replace it with individual values
- inline those values

That said, if you have a simple local definition, and you only ever reference the values and not the object itself, and the values themselves are simple constants (numbers, booleans), it is always going to be inlined.

Comment: Thanks John for the input. I believe my code meets the requirements for in lining that you laid out in the last paragraph, yet the number constants are not in lined. (I gave you an up vote since your answer is certainly helpful. I'll study your answer some more and if I see I missed any of your points, I'll come back and mark it as the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe you'll have to use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS to get any wins from inlining.  Your current code isn't valid for ADVANCED OPTIMIZATIONS currently, so I modified to make it work.

```
 /** @enum {number} @const */
 var TASK_STATUS = {
     REJECT: -1,
     UNKNOWN: 0,
     APPROVE: 1
 };

 /**
  *  @param {TASK_STATUS} a
  */
 function init_(a) {
     if (a === TASK_STATUS.UNKNOWN) {
         alert("Reject");
     } else if (a === TASK_STATUS.APPROVE) {
         alert("Unknown");
     } else {
         alert("Approve");
     }
 }

init_(TASK_STATUS.REJECT);
```

outputs:

```
alert("Approve");
```

The reason why closure compiler can't inline your code is for a few different reasons.  Closure compiler doesn't dig all the way into your code -- it generally uses type information that you pass in to make decisions.  It doesn't do well with passing functions via object expressions.  (ie, passing the init function back via object literal)

Secondly, your init function had side effects (assignment of a).  Since closure compiler didn't know what was really being changed, (no type information), it did the safe thing and didn't inline the function out.

Closure compiler in advanced mode is a beast.  It will take some getting used to.